# Hidden Markov chain: Error BaumWelch(paramHMM, obs, paramAlgo) : could not find function "setStorageMode"

Tags: r, hidden-markov-models

I am trying hard to calculate the Hidden markov chain using `RHmm` package but I always get the error such as "Error in BaumWelch(paramHMM, obs, paramAlgo) : could not find function "setStorageMode".  The detailed codes and data is given as follows.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("^TWII", src = "yahoo", from = "1900-01-01", to = "2015-12-31")
chartSeries(TWII, theme="black")
TWII_Subset<- window(TWII, start=as.Date("2013-01-01"), end=as.Date("2015-12-31"))
TWII_Train <- cbind(TWII_Subset$TWII.Close - TWII_Subset$TWII.Open)
library(RHmm)
hm_model <- HMMFit(obs=TWII_Train, dis="MIXTURE", nStates=5, nMixt=4, control=list(iter=2000))
Error in BaumWelch(paramHMM, obs, paramAlgo) : 
  could not find function "setStorageMode"
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error. I have [`RHmm`](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=85) version `2.1.0` installed.

Comment: This is a long shot but have you restarted R since you installed `quantmod` or `RHmm` ?

Comment: @Pascal Having seen some strange behavior when not restarting R after installs (i.e various errors), and since you found the error isn't reproducible, this could be environment related.  Perhaps not likely, but it doesn't hurt to start with a clean environment to rule this out (and it doesn't take long).

Comment: @Pascal Understood, but don't you end up having to re-load the packages when you restart the environment (e.g. `library(dplyr)`) ?

Comment: @Pascal and steveb I am really thankful to you for your help!! For me your Golden comments really worked. I clear every thing and start new session by using rm(list=ls()) and by pressing Alt+shift+0. Bundle of thanks for great comments!!!